# Storing generated HTML and preventing XSS attacks in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xss

I am writing an app where a lot of heavy duty calculations are performed in the browser to generate and format some content. The resulting content is HTML that I would like to save on the server (structure, links, results of calculations, etc). It does not have any javascript or CSS (in style tags).

Is there a Rails method or plugin I can use in a model's `before_save` or `after_initialize` method to strip javascript/css from the content and safely send it back to the browser (via JSON, FYI) while preventing XSS attacks, given the simple structure of the content?

Answer (score 2):

I personally use the [Sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize) gem. Using this gem you can configure what HTML elements and attributes you want to allow and the gem will strip anything else.

I'd say this is a good choice for your app because since you want to allow some HTML but disallow Javascript/CSS then a sanitizer based on a full blown HTML parser is most likely the best choice considering there are numerous ways of being crafty and injecting Javascript/CSS into HTML.